# Sort order for Area 51 Hottest Proposals?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, site-proposal, sorting

Take these two recently-created Area 51 proposals:

#### [App Store](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-store)

- Created: 27 March
- Followers: 5
- Questions: 9
- Views: 38
- Definition phase progress: 2%

#### [Spinal Muscular Atrophy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30633/spinal-muscular-atrophy)

- Created: 24 March
- Followers: 54
- Questions: 37
- Views: 450
- Definition phase progress: 29%

When I look at the [Hottest Proposals tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot), out of 510 total open proposals:

- App Store is **#1**
- Spinal Muscular Atrophy is **#509**

Comment: App Store got a lot of traffic recently. No idea where from. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84907/feed-gaping-maw

Comment: @random - I added view count to the question. I can't figure out *any* heuristic by which SMA could be considered the penultimate in hotness compared to *all* site proposals.

Comment: Maybe SMA is just wasting away due to the secret hotness algorithm

Comment: may be hotness only counts today/yesterday's activities, OR just comparing ratio between yesterday and today activities, since he proposed App Store today, eg., 9 activity means 9x hotter than yesterday.

Comment: @YOU - Now, come up with a theory which explains why [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30484/) (or [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30054/), [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28289/), [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28868/), [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29876/), [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29831/), [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29885/), [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29699/), or [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29712/)) is hotter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be better now.  Hotness is determined roughly the same way as commitment score: we look at the cross-site reputation of the users that have followed / committed to the site, and how long ago they did so.  The main difference is that the decay is a lot faster for hotness.

In this case, however, we were missing a term in the equation that meant we were way undervaluing low-rep users.  That part is fixed now, so [Spinal Muscular Atrophy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30633/spinal-muscular-atrophy) is on the front page again.  However, [App Store](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-store) still ranks above it because it has attracted much higher-rep users (who are much more likely to make the proposal & site succeed).